# Error on building Android app with sh-script

Tags: php, android, linux, shell, titanium

I try to run a shell-script to build an Android application on my Linux system. The script will be started from a php-file. I tested my script from my server console and it worked fine, just as I want... Now I try to start it from my php-script and I get the following message in my log-file:

```
path.js:360
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');
              ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at path.js:360:15
    at Array.filter (native)
    at exports.join (path.js:358:36)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js:43:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js:80:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I tried to kick off that script with multiple users from my server console, and it worked all fine. As I said from my php-file it doesn't work.
Below is a snippet of my shell-script

```
export ANDROID_SDK=/srv/sdk/android-sdk
export MOBILE_SDK=/root/.titanium/mobilesdk

cd $WORKSPACE/sample_app
titanium build --sdk '3.4.1.GA' --build-only --platform 'android' --android-sdk $ANDROID_SDK > build.log 2>&1
```

May someone can help me, please. I look desperately for solutions... Thank you.

Comment: Can you start other shell scripts from your php interpreter?

Comment: Yes, there are other commands i skipped in this snippet, which are executed. For example jarsigner, mv, cp, every other command works fine. I guess maybe nodejs is The problem, but i dont know

Comment: Now you are mixing node.js into the problem, which seems likely since the errors are from files ending in .js. Is it node.js or php you are using?

Comment: Ok. I found out that titanium build uses node.js. My guess is that if you execute the script through  `shell_exec ($cmd )` your php interpreter might not have the same privileges or environment paths as you as a user have. You might want to check the php interpreters privileges for the folders you are accessing.

Comment: As i thought, i checked the node_path with an echo , when i started the script from php and got no output

Comment: The script is probably running as the user designated to you php interpreter and that one does not have the right paths set. You just have to do it in the script I assume.

Comment: Ye thats what i thought first, but i start the script as root with a gcc-wrapper (dont know if thats the right term). I checked that and got "root" as output on "whoami".. *confused*

Comment: When you start the script yourself, do you start is as root then as well? If it runs as root it is not read/write permissions that is the problem. But the environment variables (Paths) are different from users and root might not have the right settings.